# Django/HTML - How to stay on the same page after a search

Tags: html, django, forms, url

I'm working on a Django project and I have a problem with URL pattern when I'm using form.

So I have a search bar on the home page but also on the search page doing the same search :

`/home/` and `/home/search/`

When I search for the first time it redirects me to search which is normal

from `home` to  `home/search/`.

But when I want to search again I want to stay to this `/home/search/` but it redirects me to another search like below

```
/home/search/search/
```

It says error because obviously it's not in the url pattern mentioned in urls.py

Actually what I've done is the following (I know it's dirty programming) :

```
if url contains search then <form method="post" action="">
else <form method="post" action="search/">
```

If it is in home page then go to search page but if it is in search page stay here.

I'm wondering if there is a better way to resolve this problem ?

Thanks for reading guys and I hope you will help me.

Comment: Instead of `action="search/"` do `action="."` that means the current url you're on. In your search view redirect to `home/search/` after doing a new search

Comment: Thanks it helped me :)